# Detecting server socket close with select

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a simple socket server that I'm implemented in C on linux and Windows, and am having difficulty shutting it down cleanly.

It creates a socket, binds it and then calls listen. It then loops using select to detect new connections, and also for read activity on any currently connected client sockets. A client closing the socket is fine, that wakes the select up, the bit I'm having trouble with is cleanly closing the loop down. Naively I had closed the server socket (the one I'm listening and accepting on) from a different thread, or in response to a signal or Ctrl-C, but this fails to wake the select up, which I found surprising.

I can use the self pipe trick to wait the select up if necessary (create a fifo and include the read end in the select list as well, then write to it when I want to shutdown), but that won't be hugely convenient given the structure of the code. 
I was just wondering whether this was expected behaviour, whether I would expect my select to wake when I close the server socket. It DOES work this way on Windows.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have your listening socket in read fd set of select()?

Comment: Can you simply position a global variable and send a signal to the select thread with pthread_kill?

Answer (score 1):

It is a poor idea to close a socket / file descriptor from another thread because it is prone to race conditions.

`select` call is interrupted by signals. You can detect `SIGINT` in your `select` thread by using the self-pipe trick and close sockets as necessary.

Alternatively, instead of communicating the signal number through the pipe, the signal handler can just set a global `sigatomic_t` variable which `pselect` thread would check and when `pselect` interrupted by a signal. In this case `SIGINT` must be blocked at all times except when in `pselect` call.

Comment: The actual environment that's giving me problems is my test environment where I obviously have to run the server on one thread while the tests are running on the main thread, and I then want to close the server down once the test has finished. I will have to try and work out out how to cleanly include a pipe into the structure of the code in order to do this more cleanly. Thanks.

Comment: What's unfortunate is that the self-pipe trick only works on UNIX, as on Windows the select only works with sockets. I guess the most portable solution is to create a port and bind it to localhost on an ephemeral port, then connect to it and use that as the control port for such things, so use a self-pipe socket instead of fifo. Feels heavy though.

Comment: @TomQuarendon: "*I then want to close the server down*" so your implementation does not provide any functionality to shut down the server?

Comment: @TomQuarendon I would check if Windows `select` works with [Windows `_pipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/pipe).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin. No it doesn't. Windows select is sockets only. There are ways of making sockets work with the more general Windows "WaitForMultipleObjects" call that allows you to wait for a bunch of anything (files, events, semaphores, threads, etc), but it's not straightforward.

Comment: @alk This is what I'm trying to implement. How to *cleanly* shutdown the server. You can't just "exit", that takes the whole process down. I don't want to use a timeout on the select and poll a flag, as that unnecessarily delays the shutdown. I want to wake the select up.

Comment: @TomQuarendon: Then you are best not using `select()` at all. Use `(e)poll()` on *Nix, and use `WSAEventSelect()`+`WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` on Windows (where you have a `WSAEVENT` for each socket, and a `WSAEVENT` for shutdown - this would be the closest way to achieve the self-pipe trick on Windows with minimal effort).